# qrcode for python on linux

Tags: python, qr-code

I have an error when i used pyqrcode.

```
[root@localhost python2.6]# python

Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Sep  7 2010, 07:31:57) 

[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import qrcode

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/qrcode-0.2.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/qrcode/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>

    from qrcode import _qrcode

ImportError: cannot import name _qrcode
```

How to resolve above error?

I am referring pyqrcode from http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: How did you install pyqrcode on your machine?

Comment: I have the same error. I installed on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 from source.

Comment: There's obviously something wrong with the sources.
In the qrcode package there is nothing, only the \_\_init\_\_.py file.

Comment: unrelated, why are you running as root?

Answer (score 1):

After the installation of `PIL-1.1.7` and `JCC-2.14`, I've tried to install `pyqrcode-0.2.1` from sources as you did, and also ran into the same error :
`ImportError: No module named _qrcode`. But then I've noticed that `_qrcode` is actually a lib (`_qrcode.so`). So I've tried to add it on my library path :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qrcode-0.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/qrcode/
```

And it worked ! Well actually, not quite, I ran into another error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_setExceptionTypes'
```

So I've edited the `__init__.py` file

```
# probably located under a path like this for linux
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qrcode-0.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/qrcode/

# or under a path like this for a Mac
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/qrcode-0.2.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/qrcode/
```

and commented out line 21 :

```
#  _qrcode._setExceptionTypes(JavaError, InvalidArgsError)
```

Then I was able to run their simple example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
#
# pyqrcode sample encoder

import sys, qrcode

e = qrcode.Encoder()
image = e.encode('woah!', version=15, mode=e.mode.BINARY, eclevel=e.eclevel.H)
image.save('out.png')
```

(source : http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/)

Hope it helps,

Comment: This answer got me up and running on a Mac with OSX 10.7.5. Note that I had to install 'pyqrcode' from source to get it to work. The version in pip didn't work for me. Probably something on my machine, but it's worth trying both ways if you are having problems.